# Can I turn org-mode on for a part of a buffer in another mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have a python code file with a large multiline string comment that I'm using as a sort of checklist for tests that I'm implementing.

Is it possible to have just that portion of the buffer be in org mode so I can have checkboxes and heading and stuff?

```
python code

"""
large text block
that I would like to be
in org mode
"""

more python code implementing tests
```

Note that this is org that I want to embed in a python file. Not vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure thing!

Just add this here to your init:

```
(use-package poporg
    :ensure t
    :bind ("C-c \\" . poporg-dwim))
```

Then place your cursor in the comment you want to insert Org and press `C-c \`.

Here's more info about it: https://github.com/QBobWatson/poporg

And here's a thread on Emacs Reddit about it: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/aadbf6/poporg_is_great/

Answer (score 1):

I'll look into poporg like @dangom said but one thing that I managed to figure out.

I could `clone-indirect-buffer` to another window then `narrow` that buffer to just the area in question by using a region, then enable `mmm-mode` on each one. Then finally run `mmm-parse-buffer` on each. It then seems to guess that my main buffer is `python-mode` and the buffer narrowed to just org is `org-mode`!